# What gem provides me the functionality of encrypting a string of 16 characters into a string of 24 characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I'm an encryption novice and I'm not even sure this is possible with encryption.  Any advice or direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption is built into rails -> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html heres an example -> http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/12535 I would suggest if you want to change from 16 to 24 possibly appending 8 characters to the string there are many alternative ways of doing this depending on the depth of security you are after more info about what you are doing it for could help.

Comment: Using Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("16 alphanumerics go here") provides me with a 40 character long string.

Using Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("16 alphanumerics go here" + "12345678") also provides me with a 40 character long string.

Comment: Could you provide a little more about why you want an exactly 24 char long encrypted string? most encryption is larger in size then this as the smaller this is the more likely the encryption will be broken and 24 characters seems very small.

Comment: It has nothing to do with security and only to do with rules on a toy project I've been given as training.  The wording is a bit ambiguous and I'm wondering if my mentor (this isn't schoolwork) means they want me to generate a 24 character long string that will be later encrypted.

For now I am assuming he wants me to take 16 alphanumeric ascii characters and encrypt them into a 24 character long string.

Comment: By the sounds of that he wants you to write your own encryption method as a 24 bit encryption would be almost worthless, even a 40 bit encryption could be broken in seconds with the right hardware. I would suggest taking a look at some of the base code of the encryption algorithms and the conversions they are making to the string as you will not find something specifically built for this.

Comment: well this isn't the answer I was hoping for but it's an answer none-the-less.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps he wants you to "hash" a string, rather than encrypt it? MD5 and SHA are hashing algorithms, not encryption algorithms.

Comment: Yea I was wondering that as well although again these would generally be much bigger then 24 bits if the purpose is security, checksums do range in much smaller bits  and are a form of hashing used to verify data is not corrupted this may be what he was after hard to say. If so maybe look at sum24 checksum